# iOS app behaviour after installing new version from app store

Tags: ios, version, behavior

I have an iOS app installed in iPhone from app store, now if I have an updated version 1.1 for the same app at app store and I'm getting some sort of informative alert from the older version 1.0 (New version is available...).

If I click on alertview's ok button, it redirects me to the new app link in browser. I download my new version then.

Please provide answers of following questions :

1. Will it replace old version?
2. Will it replace sqlite and image folder on the document path? (Both version is having same named sqlite file, say abc.sqlite1.0 and same folder name, say imagesToBeCopied)
3. Will it append the sqlite entitie rows with new rows for same entity?
4. How can I install version 1.0 again from app store? Is it possible to get it anyhow?

Please provide your valuable answers on it, which can help me out to reach to some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking this as a developer, or as a user?

Comment: I am asking it from both point of view. How it will behave if user is having the old version already(will it duplicate data?) and what's missing if I want to have complete new data with new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Will it replace old version?

Yes, the app bundle will be replaced by the new one

> 2.Will it replace sqlite and image folder on the document path? (Both version is having same named sqlite file, say abc.sqlite1.0 and same folder name, say imagesToBeCopied)

No, the documents directory is not affected by the update process. If you have procedures in your code that update the documents directory, they will still run, but without any changes it would be no different to a normal launch of your app - e.g. if you check for and copy if needed, something from the bundle to the documents directory, this will only happen if the target file doesn't already exist.

> 3.Will it append the sqlite entitie rows with new rows for same entity?

This is not related to the update process. If you want to modify the data as part of the update, you will write this specifically in first launch code for your new version.

> 4.How can I install version 1.0 again from app store? Is it possible to get it anyhow?

No, the updated version replaces the old one on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge...

1. Yes, the new version of the app will replace the old version.
2. Yes it will replace your sqlite file, assuming your paths did not change across versions. If you want to handle this sort of case it is your responsibility to include logic in the newer version of the app to check for the existence of the sqlite file and overwrite or modify it accordingly.
3. No, all modifications to the sqlite file need to be done manually by the new version (see #2).
4. As of now, not possible to do this through the app store. Only one version of any app can be placed for "sale" at a time. You would have to do this through other means (testflightapp.com for instance [for adhocs for devs]).